# Google Map: search for autocomplete and / or latitude - longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Currently we use the autocomplete geocoder from Google:

```
google.maps.places.Autocomplete
```

So that when users input an address, they get the suggested results, click on any of them, and they are mapped to the selected one.

I guess we could also use the Google geocoder:

```
google.maps.Geocoder
```

So that when users input an address and press enter, they get the suggested results in the same way. But also if they input a latitude and longitude and press enter, they are mapped to these coordinates.

We would need a mix of both, so that as the users are typing an address, they get some autocomplete results as they type, but if they are just entering coordinates and press enter, they are mapped to the specified latitude and longitude.

I couldn't make any of both components work that way. Autocomplete would not search for lat/long and the Geocoder would not give me an autocomplete.

Edit to clarify: So my question is if there is something (component, parameter, ad hoc solution...) I can use for our purpose: "*so that as the users are typing an address, they get some autocomplete results as they type, but if they are just entering coordinates and press enter, they are mapped to the specified latitude and longitude.*"

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: My question is if there is something (component, parameter, ad hoc solution...) I can use for our purpose : "so that as the users are typing an address, they get some autocomplete results as they type, but if they are just entering coordinates and press enter, they are mapped to the specified latitude and longitude."

Comment: I took the search to the server, so that we could have a custom autocomplete control in the browser, which would ask the server to perform the search and give some results back. But it seems this is not a good solution for us. Even if we have a proper Google Maps licence, this would overload the traffic between our server and Google, so whatever we do should be done in the browser. Any idea about how use Google Maps autocomplete and support reverse geocoding (latitude / longitude)?